# Why is my Arduino code to Write to an external Serial Flash Rom not working?

Tags: c++, arduino, embedded, spi, flash-memory

[Edit: I've added a diagram because the image I uploaded doesn't line up with the rows of the bread board because of the perspective]

I'm trying to write program code to Read and Write to an external Serial Flash Rom (a AT25SF081B) via SPI with an Arduino Nano Every. My function for reading from a page of memory on the ROM works as it returns all 1s since the Flash is blank. I've checked the contents of the buffers sent via the function param and its taking what I input but its not writing to the ROM.
[image]
How I have it wired, the AT25SF081B is on a breakout board that numbered differently then the package, its mirrored:

```
 Breakout   AT25SF081B
8|  u  |1   1|  u  |8
7|     |2   2|     |7
6|     |3   3|     |6
5|     |4   4|     |5
```

[image]
[image: Diagram of Breadboard wiring]
My sketch, I was following this [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Design-with-Discrete-SPI-Flash-Memory/) But there have been incompatibilities because I'm using an Nano Every, not sure if that is partly why it doesn't work? I've been scouring the internet for answers but can't find anything because there is more tailored to the Uno then the Nano Every.

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define DATAOUT 14 //MOSI
#define DATAIN  15 //MISO
#define SPICLOCK  16 //SCK
#define CHIPSELECT  26 // CS

//#define BASEADDRESS 000000h
//#define ENDADDRESS 0FFFFFh

//opcodes
#define WREN 0x06
#define WRDI 0x04
#define RDSR 0x05
#define READ 0x03
#define PAGE_PROG 0x02
#define ERASE 0x60
#define JEDEC 0x9f

//globals
boolean isReady(false);
String command;
//data buffer
byte output [256];

void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0;

void printPage(byte *page_buffer) {
  //Serial.println("printPage called");
  char buff[10];
  for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 16; ++j) {
      sprintf(buff, "%02x", page_buffer[i * 16 + j]);
      Serial.print(buff);
    }
    Serial.println();
  }
}

void getInfo(void) {
  Serial.println("command: getInfo");
  byte *b1, *b2, *b3;
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(JEDEC);
  *b1 = SPI.transfer(0); // manufacturer id 0x1c
  *b2 = SPI.transfer(0); // memory type 0x31
  *b3 = SPI.transfer(0); // capacity 0x14
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  //toggleCS();
  Serial.println("toggleCS exited");
  char buff[128];
  sprintf(buff, "Manufacturer ID: %02xh\nMemory Type: %02xh\nCapacity: %02xh",
    &b1, &b2, &b3);
  Serial.println(buff);
  Serial.println("Ready");
}  

void erase(void)
{
  Serial.println("Command: Erase Chip");
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(WREN);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(ERASE);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  toggleCS();
  Serial.println("Ready");
}

void readPage(unsigned int page_number)
{
  char buff[80];
  sprintf(buff, "Command: Read (%04xh)", page_number);
  Serial.println(buff);
  byte page_buffer[256];
  getPage(page_number, page_buffer);
  //printPage(output);
  Serial.println("READY");
}

void getPage(word page_number, byte *page_buffer)
{
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(READ);
  SPI.transfer((page_number >> 8) & 0xFF);
  SPI.transfer((page_number >> 0) & 0xFF);
  SPI.transfer(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    page_buffer[i] = SPI.transfer(0);
    output[i] = page_buffer[i];
  }
  if(command.startsWith("read"))
  {
    printPage(page_buffer);
  }
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  toggleCS();
}

void writeData(word page, byte offset, byte databyte)
{
  char buff[80];
  sprintf(buff, "Command: Write(%04xh, %04xh, %02xh)", page, offset, databyte);
  Serial.println(buff);
  byte page_data[256];
  getPage(page, page_data);
  page_data[offset] = databyte;
  //Serial.println("Contents of page_data array before writePage command");
  //printPage(page_data);
  writePage(page, page_data);
  Serial.println("Ready");
}

void writePage(word page_number, byte *page_buffer)
{
  //Serial.println("Contents of page_data array passed to writePage command");
  //printPage(page_buffer);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(WREN);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(PAGE_PROG);
  SPI.transfer((page_number >> 8) & 0xFF);
  SPI.transfer((page_number >> 0) & 0xFF);
  SPI.transfer(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
  {
    SPI.transfer(page_buffer[i]);
  }
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  toggleCS();
}

void toggleCS(void)
{
  //Serial.println("toggleCS called");
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(RDSR);
  while(!SPI.transfer(0) & 1) {  };
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
}

void checkForSerial() 
{
  char c;
  while (Serial.available()) {
    c = (char)Serial.read();
    //Serial.println(c);
    if (c == ';') {
      isReady = true;
    }
    else {
      command += c;
    }    
  }
  if(!Serial.available())
  {
    //Serial.println("Serial is not available");
    //delay(1000);
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(DATAOUT, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATAIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(SPICLOCK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CHIPSELECT,OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(14000000, MSBFIRST,SPI_MODE0));
  //SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Ready");

  //CPU_CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc; // enable CPU reset via command
  
  //digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH); // Disable Device
 
}

void loop() {
  checkForSerial();
  if (isReady) 
  {
    if (command == "info") {
      getInfo();
    }
    else if (command == "erase") {
      erase();
    }
    else if (command == "testWREN") {
      testWriteEnable();
    }
    // A one-parameter command...
    else if (command.startsWith("read")) {
      int pos = command.indexOf(" ");
      if (pos == -1) {
        Serial.println("Error: Command 'readPage' expects an int operand");
      } else {
        word page = (word)command.substring(pos).toInt();
        readPage(page);
      }
    }
    // A three-parameter command..
    else if (command.startsWith("write")) {
      word pageno;
      byte offset;
      byte data;
      
      String args[3];
      for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        int pos = command.indexOf(" ");
        if (pos == -1) {
          Serial.println("Syntax error in writeByte");
          goto done;
        }
        args[i] = command.substring(pos + 1);
        command = args[i];
      }
      pageno = (word)args[0].toInt();
      offset = (byte)args[1].toInt();
      data = (byte)args[2].toInt();
      writeData(pageno, offset, data);
    }
    else {
      Serial.print("Invalid command sent: ");
      Serial.println(command);
    }
done:
    command = "";
    isReady = false;
  }
  //else { Serial.print("Not ready"); }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? Is it my code? or is it my wiring? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I feel that it would be better asked at https://arduino.stackexchange.com/ as this is about more than just programming.

Comment: I feel your pain. There's nothing worse than not knowing if the problem is in the code or the hardware.

Comment: @stdunbar something also being on-topic on a different site is not a reason to be off-topic on this one

Comment: @user253751 - there isn't much wiring advice on this site.  Is wiring on-topic for stackoverflow.com?

Comment: It would be good if the asker could isolate the problem to the code. That would be 100% on topic here.

Comment: I do not follow your wiring, why pins 2,7,8 of flash connected to pin 17 on arduino?

Comment: @Slava, I was told that those should be tied to VCC by the datasheet and tutorials I've found, Pin 17 of the Nano Every is a 3.3v power output pin and the flash rom is rated for 3.3v not the normal 5v output by the Arduino's normal power out pin.

Comment: copy on Arduino SE https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/90570/why-is-my-arduino-code-to-write-to-an-external-serial-flash-rom-not-working

Comment: @emonegarand I would try making sure the `info` command works before moving to reading and writing. Reading all 0xFF might be reading the page correctly (it should start all 1s like you said) or MISO is stuck at logic high

Comment: In what way are the pins of the flash breakout board different from the pinout of the actual chip?   I would have guessed they are the same (same function vs pin number).  For example, pin 2 of the AT25SF081B is Serial Out, so connecting it to VCC makes no sense.  So the pin out is different?

Comment: @mmixLinus, the chip has 1 at the upper left, the breakout board has 1 at the upper right. Its mirrored.

Comment: @Unn when I call the getInfo function, it returns: Manufacturer ID: 3ff8h,
Memory Type: 3fe6h, Capacity: 3f96h

Comment: "I was told that those should be tied to VCC" if your diagram is correct second on the right (counting from top)  is pin 2 which is serial output. That one definately should not be conncted to VCC, pin 3 maybe (write protection)

Comment: But pin3 is connected to ground and pin 4  which is ground is unconnected. Looks like you shifted your connections.

Comment: @Slava, it looks like that but I have it connected to 4. I added a diagram because the picture makes it looks like all the wires are up one row in the bread board

Comment: Given only 2K of SRAM you have some rather large buffers on the stack.  Are you certain that you don't simply have a stack overflow?  Why not use a single static buffer for all your `sprintf` calls, and a single static page buffer for both input and output?  Without a debugger, determining stack safety is not easy.  See https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/how-to-find-out-the-maximum-used-stack-space.  On this part use of static allocation will ensure at compile time you have sufficient memory, which is better than a non-deterministic _runtime_ error when you find you haven't.

Comment: ... sorry 6K SRAM on a "Nano Every", but even so.

Comment: The `getInfo()` function is seriously flawed - fix that first then post a new question if it still does not work.  You are dereferencing unitialised pointers and writing to the result.  Then you print the address of the pointers b1, b2, b3 rather the register values you intended.   Did `Manufacturer ID: 3ff8h, Memory Type: 3fe6h, Capacity: 3f96h` not strike you are wrong?  They are not `byte` values for a start.  While not related to the write, that code may break everything.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to use you connection with a GetInfo and found that you have a problem in the pointer to bytes, try using:

```
  byte b1, b2, b3;
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(JEDEC);
  b1 = SPI.transfer(0); // manufacturer id 0x1c
  b2 = SPI.transfer(0); // memory type 0x31
  b3 = SPI.transfer(0); // capacity 0x14
  digitalWrite(CHIPSELECT, HIGH);
  //toggleCS();
  Serial.println("toggleCS exited");
  char buff[128];
  sprintf(buff, "Manufacturer ID: %02xh\nMemory Type: %02xh\nCapacity: %02xh",
    b1, b2, b3);
```

Also, I had problems in using you CS pin address, I've used pin D8(SS), and defined it as:
`#define CHIPSELECT  8 // CS`